# Musicals with ragtime songs?

Tags: piano

I need to play a song from a musical for my music assessment, I am wondering if there are any ragtime songs in a musical that can be played on piano. Oh, and not too easy please, something fun and difficult.

Comment: check "Bugsy Malone" movie

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of being a little bit on the nose, how about "Ragtime" from the musical "Ragtime"?

http://www.musicnotes.com/sheetmusic/mtd.asp?ppn=MN0055431

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=eWbIsYtDFKY